# I have a hardware-only Conway "Life Machine", is that interesting?

Tags: oscilloscope

I just finished making a hardware only Life Machine™ on breadboard using 74LSxx chips. I call it The Life Machine™ or Life from Scratch™. It works on an analog oscilloscope in X-Y-Z mode. The field is 256 x 256 pixels in size, and it is set up to run at 4 MHz at a 60 Hz frame-rate, but because of some glitching with the capacitance issues on the breadboard setup, it works well at 1 MHz, 15 Hz framerate. There is one generation per frame, so the design, if properly moved onto a reasonable PCB or wire-wrap board would probably be easily scaleable to a field of 512 x 512 pixels at 60 Hz with an 16 MHz crystal or from there onward. (Thinking about doing a VGA 800x600 mode or jumping straight to HDMI 1080.)

My algorithm is quite highly optimized so that it runs in a single pass. There is no CPU involved and no micro-controller, no code, its 100% pure hardware automaton. No FPGA. Just RAM, counters, bus transceivers, latches, and a hard-wired neighbor-count-adder with one breadboard slice of 1-bit full-adders, AND, OR, XOR, and inverter chips. No higher order display chip either, even the DAC for the X-Y deflection I made myself from R-2R resistor ladders. And you were all part of it since I had a number of questions recently to all sorts of different aspects of this.

I wonder whether there is interest in this or if this has been done many times before? I wonder how I should publish this? Do you think there is any journal that would have any interest in this? I could imagine I am perhaps 40 years late to the party, but when googling I have not found nether the hardware only setup quite like mine nor have I found my algorithm being discussed and the way it's implemented. I find my solution very nifty.

Are there still hobby-electronics or semi-professional magazines or journals around these days? Or might some IEEE journal be interested in this?

Comment: Maybe write about it, host it somewhere (e.g. github) and submit to Hackaday?

Comment: Is it the Cambridge U's Game of Life? But I never heard of the term "Life Machine". Can you show us a photo of your machine? Does it weight one hundred pounds? Is it programmable? The inventor John Conway, must be regret not able to see your fake machine before he caught the covid virus.

Comment: My apologies that I did not read your long question carefully. Your title says Conway already. So I have been asking stupid questions. Sorry about that. Cheers. BTW.do you have a schematic?

Comment: This sounds very interesting.  I would do a write up and submit it to several places.  Nuts&Volts, EEVBlog, etc.  Have you considered making a Youtube video?

Comment: Thanks @evildemonic, Nuts & Volts appears to be the right venue where I can write it up. I considered YouTube, as the Ben Eater series really got me started, but to arrive at his level of quality takes a lit of effort and experience. I find writing easier and more useful to the recipient.

Comment: @tlfong01, apologies accepted, in fact I found your first comment pretty funny! I use the same technology that built the VAX 11/780 but I do not arrive at the same weight and bulk, haha. Maybe I could do it in discrete BJT or vacuum tubes or relays to get there. :)

Comment: Just to note for those that may not know:  While the main Hackaday website is a blog that posts articles about news items or projects found on other sites, Hackaday also has a sub-site that is dedicated specifically to showcasing user's own private projects.  The site is called hackaday.io and there is a link to the sub-site at the top of the main Hackaday homepage...

Answer (score 2):

Given that it bulky in today’s world and not cheap, the attraction will be to those with Rube Goldberg and philosophical time on their hands. But the process of making it might be of great interest to some.  a video is worth 64k words. what’s better?  Call it a Covid 19 simulator then you get a lot of interest. And inject HCQ seeds with Zinc and Vit ABCDK for patterns. Then add colloidal gold patterns with C60 and azythromyacin and virus  and bigger bacteria looking objects. Then design innate immunity objects in the corner to obliterate the CV19. Add humour then the video might go viral. Puny pun intended.
So target the geeky guys and the organic ones with the anti-HCQ hoaxers (big Pharma and insurance law suits on Dr’s.)

Then see if you can reverse engineer a happy face to get the seed or some other symbolic.

Life is simply an application of Ohm’s Law , luck and Heisenberg principle. Yet your challenge to spread an anti-virus combination needs no manager CPU’s just logic and a good formula.

On the 4Mhz watch out for crosstalk and  prevent race errors by phasing clocks, grounding or UTP wires for clock or use your finger on signals  to make it worse with 100pF and then you are closer to the sensitive signal to making faster.

You might be able to make it even faster, using pullup R’s or Vcc+5% or adding 30pF.

Any scope with a very short ground connection is your pal.  Like no clip and tip with spring and two test pins sig + GND on 10:1 probe.  Or use RF cap to earth GND.

Comment: Ha, that's a funny reply. You got all boxes checked, except, it's colloidal silver, not gold. :D

Comment: Colloidal gold is even better

Comment: Silver is cheaper but just for bacteria.